# jQuery after ajax plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a plugin to rate values: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm

The following code works if I put directly into the HTML.

```
<li>
    <p><strong>Product</strong>
        <br/>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" id="rateit" data-role="none">
        <div class="rateit" id="rateitHover" data-rateit-backingfld="#rateit" data-rateit-resetable="false"  data-rateit-ispreset="true"
        data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="5">
        </div>
    </p>
</li>
```

The code below doesn't work, it retrieves the default `<input type="range">` by html.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, item) 
    {
        info += "<li id='" + item.id + "'>" +
        "<p><strong>" + item.product + "</strong><br/>" +
        "<input type='range' value='0' step='1' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "'/>" +
        "<div class='rateit' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "' data-rateit-backingfld='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "' data-rateit-resetable='false'  data-rateit-ispreset='true' " +
        "data-rateit-min='0' data-rateit-max='5'></div></p></li>";
    });
    $("#listviewA").append(info); 
    $("#listviewA").trigger("change");
    $("#listviewA").listview("refresh");
});
```

How do I turn this into that plugin? Thanks!

Comment: Is the code doing anything? Can you see the ajax call being made (in the net panel of firebug for example)?

Comment: Hello, yes, without any problem. The listview is filled with elements from PHP with that code. The problem is that also fills with the rate in the default format of range of html -> this one http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on your 4th/5th line. Take a look at your "'s you have an extra.

```
    info += "<li id='" + item.id + "'><p><strong>" + item.product + "</strong><br/>" +
    "<input type='range' value='0' step='1' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "'/>" +
    "<div class='rateit' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "' data-rateit-backingfld='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "' data-rateit-resetable='false'  data-rateit-ispreset='true' " +
    "data-rateit-min='0' data-rateit-max='5'></div></p></li>";
```

Comment: First of all thanks, you're right and I've edited/correct that. Although, that's not the problem, since in my code everything is working fine. I do receive the items.ID, etc..but the rate appears like the default HTML.

Comment: I have my Javascript code after the `<body> tag` and the call of scripts before the `<body> tag`, could that be the problem?

Comment: Calling unloaded script will show method undefined error in console. No error means that is not a problem. Can you update the question with corrected code segments so that we can figure the problem out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found that this is some kind of bug or something. I've tested with another plugins and doesn't work either. I'm now using a better plugin, which is more easier.
https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

The html is very simple: `<div id="score"></div>`, although it is necessary to call it on jQuery.

```
$("#score").raty({
    score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating');
    }
});
```

I've tried to adapt it and make all IDs uniques:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, item) 
    {
        info += "<li id='" + item.id + "'>" +
        "<p><strong>" + item.product + "</strong><br/>" +
        "<input type='range' value='0' step='1' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "'/>" +
        "<div id=" + 'score' + item.id + "></div></p></li>";
    });
    $("#listviewA").append(info); 
    $("#listviewA").trigger("change");
    $("#listviewA").listview("refresh");
});
```

But continues not to work. I've tried in vain also:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item) 
        {
            info += "<li id='" + item.id + "'>" +
            "<p><strong>" + item.product + "</strong><br/>" +
            "<input type='range' value='0' step='1' id='" + 'rateIt' + item.id + "'/>" +
            "<div id=" + 'score' + item.id + "></div></p></li>";

            $("#score" + item.id).raty({
                score: function() {
                    return $(this).attr('data-rating');
                }
            });
        });
        $("#listviewA").append(info); 
        $("#listviewA").trigger("change");
        $("#listviewA").listview("refresh");
    });
```

Btw, I'm loading this function before page show..I don't know if that's the problem.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#main", function() {
    $(function(){
        get_info();
    });
})
```